# Как использовать значение data атрибута в скрипте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать чтобы при клике на span с классом timestamp, устанавливалось то количество секунд, которое указано в атрибуте data-timestamp?

```js
$('.timestamp').click(function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].currentTime = 5
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="timestamp" data-timestamp="10">00:00:10</span>
<span class="timestamp" data-timestamp="20">00:00:20</span>
<span class="timestamp" data-timestamp="30">00:00:30</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.timestamp').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data().timestamp);
    // $(this).data().timestamp  надо применить там, где необходимо, соответственно
    //document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].currentTime = 5
});
```

```css
span { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="timestamp" data-timestamp="10">00:00:10</span>
<span class="timestamp" data-timestamp="20">00:00:20</span>
<span class="timestamp" data-timestamp="30">00:00:30</span>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141623/discussion-on-answer-by------data-).